# Angular. Export html to excel. Doesn't work on firefox and ie. But work in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, export-to-excel

It's work on chrome, but doesn't work in firefox and IE.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uyJ4.png) - may be problem in this?

Comment: You forgot to add the actual code into your question. Please edit and fill in the necessary information.

Comment: You can use ALASQL it directly takes value from $scope and export it to excel. See the following link to learn how to use it
http://alasql.org/